# No hotkeys working at all in blender

Tags: shortcut

Keyboard is working fine on my computer. It's possible to type in text-boxex. It's possible to use special keys such as: tab, space, alt, ctrl, shift, arrows. But none of the letters works.

While typing letters, I can see that being logged in the terminal:

```
wm_event_add_ghostevent Send double click
```

My OS is linux with gentoo.

As I said, letters aren't working so any combination of letters with modifiers doesn't work. But letters alone also don't work. The hotkeys are all defined correctly (default setup). If I open the settings and try to change a shortcut, I can press on the shortcut and it shows "press a key". If I press ctrl, shift, alt. I can see that it's seeing it but any other letter or combination isn't being detected...

What's strange is that I can type text in inputs. Which means that at some point the keyboard is detecting everything.

Second tests, I opened the configuration panel and tried to assign a new hotkey. I discovered two stranges behaviour!

If I click on the box that allow us to select an event, If I press a letter, it does nothing. If I press a letter and move my cursor, it changes the event to "Mouse" -> <kbd>In-between move</kbd>. That's the really strange part. If I open the dialog by pressing the arrow, it gives more options. If I click in the box that allow key selection by pressing, pressing a letter will set the key to what it was when the key was pressed.

If I set it to <kbd>tab</kbd>, clicking an other time will allow me to set the key, but pressing any letter except numbers, tab, arrows and other special char will just reset it back to <kbd>tab</kbd>. Pressing a number will set a number. What's strange is that inside the advanced dialog it detects the key press, but in the list, it detect a mouse in between or nothing until I press one of the detected keys.

Second question, if this question is all about keyboard imports... Could anyone explain what does that mean?

Comment: I don't know much about the internal details of Linux, but it is my OS. Perhaps you could try starting the program from a gui instead of the terminal. That way it doesn't assume you are typing into the terminal.

Comment: @X-27 what do you mean by keyboard imports? the hotkeys are well defined.

Comment: @UncleSnail I started it from the command line just to check for error logs. The behaviour is the same.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you have hotkeys for your OS conflicting with them. In that case, the OS will take priority, and stop all Blender shortcuts from working. I had this problem with the <kbd>alt</kbd> key, but that's just one key. Perhaps your version of Linux "reserves" all the hotkeys, and a program must "take them back" before it can use any, or it will be overridden. Have you ever had this problem with other programs like Gimp or Firefox? I think you have to find out how your OS runs keyboard shortcut priority.

Comment: @UncleSnail no problem on other applications. As I said, it prevent letters to be detected. Like pressing "x" won't delete an object in the scene. Pressing "s" won't start the scaling mode and so on. It's not really hotkeys such as combinations of "alt", "shift", "ctrl"... Thoses keys are detected but the letters aren't. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: What version of Blender is used ? It's possible this is a bug so try installing other versions of program

Comment: @MrZak 2.72b I tried installing other versions but same problem.

Comment: @MrZak same problem on 2.76b I guess it might be a problem with my OS. I believe it could be related to GHOST that isn't guessing my keyboard right but I don't where to fix that. (I could fix that)

Comment: I'd suggest [reporting this in the bug tracker](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/2217).

Comment: @gandalf3 it's there already... https://developer.blender.org/T47228

Comment: I finally got it to work... It's a bug in Blender obviously but there is a work around it.